# What is the best way to send image file to server: as base64 or image file?

Tags: php, angularjs, image, yii2

I have an app with `REST` on `AngularJS/PHP(Yii)`;
I'm not good in backend.
I'm interesting what is the best way to upload a picture to server.
I'm using `Angular Material` directive and get image in `base64` format.

- Should I post image as `base64`?
- Or it's better to convert it and what format?
- Or maybe (It's not my opinion) to upload it from `html` `form` directly
  to backend using `Yii`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you trying to upload an image file from restangular,

Try the following code:

```
function upload($scope.image) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append($scope.image);
Restangular.one('/* your url*/').withHttpConfig({transformRequest:angular.identity})
                .customPOST(formData, '', undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined})  }
```

**by setting the content type undefined browser will automatically detect file type**

that will handle your UI side.  I have less idea about yii framework, but in following you can get the image file by using following type:

**java : @ResponseBy : multipart/form-data**,

**php : $_file**

I think its better to upload file using form-data.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to display those uploaded images on a website or mobile application, you can use [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io). Easy API to upload and you get an URL for displaying that image. It will take care of optimization and also provides URL-based parameters for resizing, cropping etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a base64 data url representation of the file as you are saying, then you can convert that into a file Blob, add a name to it and upload the Blob as data file.